# Rails retrieve record field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have database full of data, in database I have fields like `title, name, surname`. I can retrieve whole record as JSON by doing `GET` request on `/users/1.json`. What if I want to retrieve just name field for that record, is something like this `/users/1/name.json` possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  member do
    match ':attribute_name' => "users#get_attribute_value"
  end
end


# User controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def get_attribute_value
    attribute_name = params[:attribute_name]
    @user = User.where(id: params[:id])
    if User.column_names.include?(attribute_name.to_s)
      render json: { "#{attribute_name}" => @user.send(attribute_name) } 
    else
      # trying to access an attribute that does not exists
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Minor omission, I believe the `users#get_attribute_value` part in the routes needs to be quoted.